# cordova-plugin-email-composer with image attachment on android error "couldn't attach file"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, email-attachments

I am using `ionic/cordova` with an email plugin from https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/blob/cab303d/README.md

I have a canvas on my page which I am trying to attach to an email. The code is

```
var img_data = $scope.canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // also tried "image/jpeg"
var options = { attachments: [ img_data ], 
      subject: 'Enjoy!', 
      body: 'See', 
      isHtml: true};
$cordovaEmailComposer.open(options);
```

This causes a question on which email app to use (selected gmail). But it does not attach the picture to email, only a message "Couldn't attach file." The body text is present in the email composer window.

What am I missing? Much appreciate your help. This does send with attachment when sending emails from-iphone6-to-iphone6-only.

Answer (score 0):

look at example:

```
attachments: 'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8CAYAAAA6/...'
```

String starts with 'base64', but toDataURL returns string like 'data: image/png...'